# How to extract only selected values from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, extract

How to extract only the values for name, job and country

```
 identity: {'name': 'Emma', 'count': 56, 'job': 'Actress', 'country': 'UK'}
 Emma, an Actress, from UK
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "extract"? Do you mean creating a new dictionary?

Comment: Are you asking how to create the string you show underneath?

Comment: `dict.get('name')` will get you the name, etc.

Comment: yes , the printed output should be  Emma, an Actress, from UK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a string, more [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/get.html)

```
data = {'name': 'Emma', 'count': 56, 'job': 'Actress', 'country': 'UK'}
```

```
to_text = f'{data.get("name")} an {data.get("job")} from {data.get("country")}'
```

Comment: instead of `data.get("name")` you could also write `data["name"]`, even in an f-string. the only difference is that, for an invalid key, `.get()` will return None, while the `[]` will throw an IndexError. depending on situation, one may prefer one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason your program returns not just the name, job and country, but also the count, is because you didn't apply a filter. You can try:

```
data = {'name': 'Emma', 'count': 56, 'job': 'Actress', 'country': 'UK'}
info = ['name', 'job', 'country']
print([data[v] for v in data if v in info])
```

Output:

```
['Emma', 'Actress', 'UK']
```